# Babelfish for Aurora PostgreSQL not returning generated row id

Tags: java, sql-server, postgresql, amazon-web-services, babelfish

We recently converted our SQL Server database to AWS Aurora PostgreSQL(v.13.6).

We're using [Babelfish](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/babelfish/) for Aurora PostgreSQL to connect to the database with Java 8 & JDBC & SQL Server driver.  While testing, we discovered that Babelfish does NOT return generated row id on SQL insert statements (code below).  **How can this be fixed?**

SQL Server driver:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>10.2.1.jre8</version>
 </dependency>
```

However, the same test code works when using the PostgreSQL URL & postgres driver.  (returns the generated row id)

Postgres driver:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>42.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Test code:

```java
    private void testInsert(String dbUrl, String sql) {
        logger.debug("dbUrl: {}", dbUrl);
        try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                dbUrl, DBUtil.DB_USERNAME, DBUtil.DB_PASSWORD);
             PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS)) {
            setValues(ps);
            conn.setAutoCommit(false); // begin Transaction
            logger.debug("executeUpdate: {}", sql);

            int rows = ps.executeUpdate();

            logger.debug("rows: {}", rows);
            
            try (ResultSet rs = ps.getGeneratedKeys()) {
                logger.debug("rs: {}", rs);
                if (rs.next()) {
                    Long id = rs.getLong(1);
                    logger.debug("id: {}", id);
                }
                else {
                    logger.debug("ResultSet is empty");
                }
            }
          
            conn.rollback();
 //           conn.commit();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            logger.error(null, e);
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
# results with Babelfish URL & SQL Server driver: (returns 0 for row ID)
rows: 1
rs: SQLServerResultSet:1
id: 0

# results with PostgreSQL URL & postgres driver: (returns the row ID)
rows: 1
rs: org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet@2aceadd4
id: 1548
```